# How can I remove unnecessary text from a command line output?

Tags: macos, command-line, text-manipulation

I'm using GeekTool, which takes the output of terminal commands and turns them into Desktop widgets, and wanted to display the current battery percent of my bluetooth keyboard to the Desktop in the form of

```
Keyboard Battery: (Battery percent value)
```

In order to accomplish this, I am using the command

```
ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard |grep '"BatteryPercent" ='
```

which is from [this](http://osxdaily.com/2014/05/18/how-to-check-bluetooth-keyboard-battery-levels-from-the-command-line-on-mac-os-x/) website.

However, as mentioned on that website, this command outputs this not-very-clean-looking text (yes I need to change my batteries):

```
| |   |   |   "BatteryPercent" = 17
```

(So, for this input, I want the output `Keyboard Battery: 17`.) 
Therefore, my question is, how do I convert this into my intended format of "Keyboard Battery: *(Battery percent value)*" via the command line?

**EDIT: I have found another way to show the battery percent, using Ubersicht instead of GeekTool, thank you all for your help**

Comment: So, do you want `Keyboard Battery: 17` or `Keyboard Battery: (17)`? I.e., do you want literal parentheses in the output?

Comment: Keyboard Battery: 17

Comment: Please don’t clarify your question in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.  Several of us have put some effort into answering your question.  If you don’t want an answer any more, say so and walk away, and we’ll leave you alone.  But if you want a solution, copy our answers ***into your question*** and show the output you get ***in your question***.  Use copy & paste from our answers to your Terminal, and from your Terminal to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Please read, understand, and acknowledge this question:***

> Does the **`ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard`** command
>   output only that one line,
>   or does it also output other lines (that contain numbers)?

---

Since you want the output `Keyboard Battery: 17`,
which neither of the answers posted so far
will produce, you can

#### Build on [jehad’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1095899/354511#1095917):

<del>If the `ioreg` command outputs only the `BatteryPercent` line, then</del>

```
echo "Keyboard Battery: $(ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard | grep -oE '[0-9]+')"
```

**But if, as I suspect, the `ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard` command
outputs other lines (that contain numbers),
in addition to the `"BatteryPercent" =` line,
then the above command will *also* output many other lines with numbers.**

If, **as you have implicitly confirmed,**
the `ioreg` command outputs other lines (that contain numbers), then

```
echo "Keyboard Battery: $(ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard | grep BatteryPercent | grep -oE '[0-9]+')"
```

jehad’s revised answer might work
if the `ioreg` command outputs only the `BatteryPercent` line,
although it may require small changes.

#### Build on [Buffalo Rabor’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1095899/354511#1095917):

Buffalo Rabor’s revised answer will work,
with the proviso that it includes explicit parentheses in the output. 
But it can be simplified — you hardly ever need to pipe `grep` into `awk`:

```
ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard | awk '/BatteryPercent/ {print "Keyboard Battery: "$7}'
```

#### P.S.

I don’t have a Mac either,
so I can’t be sure what will work for you and what won’t.

Comment: echo "Keyboard Battery: $(ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard | grep -oE '[0-9]+')"  outputs many other lines with numbers, as does the second and third commands that you have provided.  In addition, both Buffalo's and jehad's answers do not work, with jehad's revision resulting in sed: 1: "s/.*"([[:digit:]]*)".*/ ...": \1 not defined in the RE and Buffalo's second option, while it was outputting different earlier, now outputs ='|awk '{print $5, $6, $7}' "BatteryPercent" = 51
awk: can't open file BatteryPercent
 source line number 1

Comment: As I and @G-Man have warned, we do not have Mac.  And we can only test on our GNU sed, which is almost certainly not the same as in Mac OS.  If you experiment, I'm sure you can get a variation of one of our solutions to work.  For example, "\1 not defined" error could mean that you need to use '\' before the brackets, so the part `([[:digit:]]*)` becomes `\([[:digit:]]*\)`.

Comment: @D4rKP01s0n: It would be unusual for a command to work one day and fail explosively the next day, unless catastrophic changes have been made to the system in the interim.  It is more likely that you have made a typing error.  In particular, if you are getting an error message that begins with `='|awk`, you have probably mistyped the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

To get just the number, change the "`grep`" in your example to the following:

```
grep -oE '[0-9]+'
```

This should work (at least the grep syntax will certainly work on Linux), but I don't have a Mac, so you may need to tweak it a little to get it to work.

Explanation:

- The above grep is extracting just the number part of the output.
- 'o' option says show ONLY the match.
- 'E' option says use regular expression for matching.
- '[0-9]+' is the regular expression to find numbers (+ means one or more).

Therefore, this grep command will find just the number part of the output string.

..

EDITED... after a second reading, seems like you need the number appended to the end of "Keyboard Battery:", so here is a solution using sed:

```
ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard | sed -r 's/.*=[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]*).*/Keyboard Battery: \1/;'
```

In this case, you're replacing the original string with one that begins with "Keyboard Battery: ".

Again, hope it works on Mac!

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try this out on my Mac when I get back to it and will mark this as the answer if it works

Comment: You might want to change that to `sed 's/.* \([0-9][0-9]*\).*/Keyboard Battery: \1/'`.

Comment: @G-Man why would you need two classes of digit?  The same effect can be had with the plus (one or more) operator; `[0-9]+`, or you can use an even more short-hand `\d+`.  In my experience the more verbose `[[:digit:]]` class is more widely supported (like I say, don't have a Mac, so wanted something more likely to work).  The reason for `[[:digit:]]*` in my answer (instead of `[[:digit:]]+`) is because I don't know the possible output of `ioreg`, so best to have a match than no match (no match would return just the original string).

Comment: @jehad: I use  *RE* *RE* \*  because my version of `sed` doesn’t recognize `+`.  Also, it doesn’t recognize `\d`.  A problem with  *RE* \*  is that it can match a null string.  I don’t understand why you prefer that to getting no match; if your `[[:digit:]]*` matches a null string, then your `\1` is null, and you mangle the input line (possibly discarding a number somewhere else in the line).  Also, I find that `sed` treats `(` and `)` as non-special characters, and needs `\(`…`\)` to capture a substring (→ `\1`).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Your command is flawed in that (1) it expects the number in the input to be surrounded by quotes (it isn’t), (2) it inserts quotes into the replacement string (not desired), and (3) it inserts `:  ` into the replacement string *twice*. Also, the `;` is unnecessary.

Comment: @G-Man Thanks for taking the time to check in detail.  I've tested mine and it works as I expect and as I've described, and my experience of sed is contradictory to what you're telling me (I would disagree with your points, but no need)... hmm, this is getting interesting; there's stuff I can learn here.  I'm currently using sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2, which is what comes packaged with Linux/Ubuntu 14.04.  Could you please tell me what version of sed you use, I would like to try it out?

Comment: @G-Man, again thanks for checking, you've made me take a second look, and I noticed that I incorrectly assumed the number was enclosed in double quotes and that there was a requirement for double quotes on the output.  So, I've edited my solution further.

Comment: @jehad: This is interesting. My `sed` (invoked with `--version`) ***also*** says `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`.  (I'm running it on Cygwin.) I wonder whether we have something significant different in our environments.

Comment: I've learned my lesson.  "I must leave well alone any questions involving Mac, when I have no Mac".  :-)  However our environments differ, we seem to be causing more trouble for the poor original-poster.

Answer (score 1):

pipe to awk...

```
$ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard |grep '"BatteryPercent" ='|awk '{print $5, $6, $7}'
"BatteryPercent" = 51
```

or

```
$ioreg -c AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard |grep '"BatteryPercent" ='|awk '{print "Keyboard Battery: ("$7")"}'
Keyboard Battery: (51)
```